# Warning: ftp_get(): Data connection already open; Transfer starting. But we get connection error

Tags: ftp

> Warning: ftp_get(): Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
> in /home2/public_html/downloadfiles.php on line 90 Connection error !

Here is the code:

```
ftp_get($ftp_conn, '/URSS/PX2002156.pdf', 'workorders/PX2002156.pdf', FTP_BINARY,0)
```

Here is ftp server connection:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21, 10);
if($ftp_conn){
     $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
     ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
}
```

The file is not transferred from FTP server to web server.

Comment: hi martin, thanks for your response. yes i got the problem at ftp sub-folder level permission. 0777 permission solve the problem.